# How to pass bytes data in payload during invoking AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I have on Lambda function which input is

```
input_str = "<html><body><h1>Title</h1><Hello World></body></html>"
input_base64 = base64.b64encode(bytes(input_str, 'utf-8'))
payload = {"html_base64" : input_base64}
```

here `input_base64` is bytes type variable

I am invoking this Lambda function from other Lambda function, but I am not able pass this payload

```
invoke_response = lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName="vivek_05",
                                       InvocationType='RequestResponse',
                                       Payload=payload
                                       )
```

Getting following exception:

```
  "errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter Payload, value: {'html_base64': b'PGh0bWw+PGJvZHk+PGgxPlRpdGxlPC9oMT48SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ+PC9ib2R5PjwvaHRtbD4='}, type: <class 'dict'>, valid types: <class 'bytes'>, <class 'bytearray'>, file-like object",
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Please try `Payload=json.dumps(payload)`.

Comment: @IftekharDani: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `encode` and `decode` bytes using this example. This might help you.

**Encode by :**

```
Payload=json.dumps({
            'imageName': image_name,
            'imageBytes': base64.b85encode(image_bytes).decode('utf-8'),
    })
```

**You can decode by :**

```
let imageBytes = base64.b85decode(event['imageBytes']);
let imageName = event['imageName'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the data is a binary or bytes, you need to convert into string before sending it across.

> input_base64str = str(input_base64,'utf-8')

Should fix it.

When you convert back, change it to bytes and pass it to base64 decoder.

> input_base64 = bytes(input_base64str, 'utf-8')

Hope it helps.